# Using controls without affecting the image size

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

I have the following tree in `forest`:

```
\documentclass{article}                          


\usepackage{forest}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\tikzset{
    %Define standard arrow tip
    >=stealth'}



\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{forest}
for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,align=center,base=bottom}
[AgrP
        [Spec-AgrP,name=specagr]
        [Agr$'$
                [Agr
                        [\textit{-ait},name=ait]]
                [NegP
                        [Spec-NegP
                                [\textit{pas},name=pas]]
                        [Neg$'$
                                [Neg
                                        [\textit{ne},name=ne]]
                                [TP
                                        [Spec-TP]
                                        [T$'$
                                                [T
                                                        [\textit{-er-},name=er]]
                                                [VP
                                                        [Spec-VP
                                                                [\textit{Marie},name=marie]]
                                                        [V$'$
                                                                [V
                                                                        [\textit{parl-},name=parl]]]]]]]]]]
\draw[->,dotted] (parl.south west) .. controls +(225:1cm) and +(south:0.4cm) .. (er.south);
\draw[->,dotted] (er.south west) .. controls +(left:1cm) and +(south:0.4cm) .. (ne.south);
\draw[->,dotted] (ne.south west) .. controls +(left:1cm) and +(south:0.4cm) .. (ait.south);
\draw[->,dotted] (marie.-90) .. controls +(225:6cm) and +(250:3cm) .. (specagr.-90);
\end{forest}
\caption{\label{abb-Pollock} Pollock's Analysis of \emph{Marie ne parlerait pas}}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

When I compile it, the caption is far away from the picture. The reason is the specification 6cm in the control point. So `tikz` seems to take the control point into account when determining the image size. Is there anything I can do about this? I shortened the 6cm but this gives other curves.

Comment: Is `tikz-qtree` required? If so, surely once should be sufficient for any package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can place the `\draw` commands in a `pgfinterruptboundingbox` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}                          


\usepackage{forest}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\tikzset{
    %Define standard arrow tip
    >=stealth'}



\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{forest}
for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,align=center,base=bottom}
[AgrP
        [Spec-AgrP,name=specagr]
        [Agr$'$
                [Agr
                        [\textit{-ait},name=ait]]
                [NegP
                        [Spec-NegP
                                [\textit{pas},name=pas]]
                        [Neg$'$
                                [Neg
                                        [\textit{ne},name=ne]]
                                [TP
                                        [Spec-TP]
                                        [T$'$
                                                [T
                                                        [\textit{-er-},name=er]]
                                                [VP
                                                        [Spec-VP
                                                                [\textit{Marie},name=marie]]
                                                        [V$'$
                                                                [V
                                                                        [\textit{parl-},name=parl]]]]]]]]]]
\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\draw[->,dotted] (parl.south west) .. controls +(225:1cm) and +(south:0.4cm) .. (er.south);
\draw[->,dotted] (er.south west) .. controls +(left:1cm) and +(south:0.4cm) .. (ne.south);
\draw[->,dotted] (ne.south west) .. controls +(left:1cm) and +(south:0.4cm) .. (ait.south);
\draw[->,dotted] (marie.-90) .. controls +(225:6cm) and +(250:3cm) .. (specagr.-90);
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\end{forest}
\caption{\label{abb-Pollock} Pollock's Analysis of \emph{Marie ne parlerait pas}}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```